Windows 10 Driver for NetMos 9835 PCI Multi-I/O Controller
Main goal: To have a windows 10 driver for a PCI RS232 Card: "NetMos 9835 PCI Multi-I/O Controller".
I need a driver for a PCI RS232 Card ( it has 2 serial ports ). These cards are quite old and the manufacturer doesn't provide drivers for windows 10.
I took a look at windows Xp driver of this cards, it has 2 .INF files: one of the multifunction class and the other is of Ports class configuring its ports , the latter uses serial.sys and serenum.sys .
On the device Manager , this card should appear under multifunction device ( its driver file is mf.sys). Besides, two serial ports should appear under "Ports (COM & LPT)" and utilize serial.sys and serenum.sys.
Knowing that I have serial.sys and serenum.sys in my system ( in C:\Windows\System32\drivers ), do you think it's possible to generate a driver by manually creating a INF file and using those system files or do I need to design the driver from scratch?
I am pretty familiar with C but not a expert, and I followed the first KMD Microsoft tutorial, so I know the basis of driver development.
It is my first time dealing with drivers, any guidance or advice would be appreciated.
Here are some of my attemps:

I tried to generate de driver using Visual Studio and a driver sample of serial ( https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/main/serial/serial ) but the latter doesn't support multiport devices and I couldn't find a multifunction driver sample anywhere.

I tried to manually create a driver package:



I edited INF files of windows XP driver.
I copied serial.sys and serenum.sys to the same directory
I generated the catalogue using Inf2Cat tool ( C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\x86\inf2Cat.exe )
I signed my driver package using signtool.exe
I installed the driver ( right click on .inf file > Install )
The Card is recognised as a multifunction device but doesn't work (Error codes in Device Manager in Windows) and no additional ports are listed in the device manager under "Ports (COM & LPT)" section.

